# How to find dimension of eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

## Given $\lambda$ = 2 and matrix A:

A =
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

My textbook says that to find the eigenvectors of $\lambda = 2$, solve the homogeneous linear system represented by $(2I - A)x = 0$.

$2I - A$ =
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

"This implies that $x_2$ = 0".

How is the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
computed and how does this imply that $x_2$ = 0? My textbook does not give an explanation.

Comment: The matrix that you're asking about is really $2I-A$, just the operations directly on the matrices, there's not really anything to the computation...

Comment: The rank of $2I-A$ is the codimension of the eigenspace $E_2$.

Comment: @Evan Kim  This is the second question regarding this matrix and this exercise in general. Maybe you should read again about eigenvalues, characteristic polynomial, kernel, rank, dimension... It seems that the definitions are not completely clear. I feel it would be better for you if you first go back to study the concepts

Comment: $\dim \ker(2I-A) = 3-\mathrm{rank}(2I-A)=3-1=2$

Comment: @Federico The issue is that I am having a difficult time grasping the definitions in the study material assigned to me in class. I do agree that these are trivial questions that should be self-explanatory though yet I have still struggled the entire semester. An example is the book explains rank and dimension and I understand that, but it fails to provide a connection between concepts in different chapters and perhaps expect us to see these connections by ourselves.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)? Also, given a matrix, do you know how to compute its rank? One possible way is to [row-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) it. In our case, $2I-A$ is already in row echelon form, so its rank is obviously $1$.

Comment: Alternatively, in this case you can see that $\ker(2I-A)=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,e_3\}$, so the dimension is $2$.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the rank-nullity theorem. I failed to consider it in the context of finding the dimension of the eigenspace. It is pretty obvious in hindsight now and I feel pretty dumb for overlooking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $2I-A$ is simply computed as $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
If a vector $x$ with coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3$ satisfies $(2I-A)x=0$, then it must be that $x_2=0$. This is because $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}-x_2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ so we must have $x_2=0$. Notice that $x_1$ and $x_3$ can be any number, so what does this tell you about the dimension of the eigenspace (i.e. the dimension of $\{x\in\mathbb C^3:(2A-I)x=0\}$)?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\vec x=\vec 0 \implies \vec x=(x_1,0,x_3)$$

therefore what is the dimension of the eigenspace?

Answer (score 0):

You must find all a basis for the space of vectors such that:

$A\mathbf v = \lambda \mathbf v$

and with a little algebra
$(A- \lambda I)\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$

If $x_2 \ne 0$

$(A- 2I)\mathbf v = \begin{bmatrix} x_2\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \ne \mathbf 0$